# Query in NDB database

Tags: google-app-engine

I have an ndb model which has a field

```
 name = ndb.StringProperty(required=True,
       verbose_name=translation.ugettext('Name'))
tags = ndb.StringProperty(repeated=True)
```

tags may be like (A,B,C,D) so suppose my db have the following values:

Ashish a,b,c,d
Ankur e,b,c,d
Ashu g,e,f,g

Now I want a query which will filter according to b in string tags so my desired output for above values will be:

Ashish a,b,c,d
Ankur e,b,c,d

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [google doc on this](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queries). As they point out, you need to use a model.Tags = 'b'. it should return all the objects with at least b in their tags.  I don't see what more you need than the normal doc (or I'm missing something major here)

Answer (score 0):

Greater than `>` operator returns anything that has the value.

`User.query(User.tags >= 'b')`